# Flutter: Segmented Button assigning values

Tags: flutter

I am having trouble getting a value out of a segmented button. The visuals and functionality of the button works fine but it doesn't change a value that it returns.

enum Calendar { yes, no }

```
SegmentedButton<Calendar>(
                segments: const <ButtonSegment<Calendar>>[
                  ButtonSegment<Calendar>(
                    value: Calendar.yes,
                    label: Text('YES'),
                  ),
                  ButtonSegment<Calendar>(
                    value: Calendar.no,
                    label: Text('NO'),
                  ),
                ],
                selected: <Calendar>{calendarView},
                onSelectionChanged: (Set<Calendar> newSelection) {
                  if(/*Value*/){
                      isSafe = true;
                    }else{
                      isSafe = false;
                    }
                  setState(() {
                    calendarView = newSelection.first;
                    
                    safetyMessage = 'Currently Safe: $isSafe';
                  });
                },
              ),
```

at /* value */ it should be the condition, but I'm not sure what to set it to.

Comment: I have a flimsy solution of setting /*value*/ to isSafe and having isSafe originally = true (causing its value to just switch to !isSafe) but I want it to set the value of isSafe to true or false